# Curses - How to insert predefined name of INPUT items?

Tags: curses, python-curses

How to please insert predefined name of INPUT items ?

My efforts: (info: the character "_" is cursor)

```
def Edit_Item(stdscr, item_name)
    stdscr.addstr(1, 2, "Item Name:")
    r = stdscr.getstr(2, 16, 15)
    return r

Edit_Item(stdscr, 'Foo')
Edit_Item(stdscr, 'Bar')
```

Result:

```
Item Name: _
Item Name: _
```

The desired result:

```
Item Name: Foo_
Item Name: Bar_
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I put my question wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The [*window*.`getstr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.getstr) function reads new data from the keyboard (and puts it in the screen).  Perhaps you meant [*window*`.instr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.instr), since you seem to assume that you can read back the data added in `addstr` calls.

The parameter `item_name` is not used in the sample function.  You *could* have written that to the screen using `window.addstr`, along with padding underscores (that was not done).  You could have done this:

```
def Edit_Item(stdscr, item_name)
    stdscr.addstr(1, 2, "Item Name:" + item_name + "_" )
    r = stdscr.getstr(2, 16, 15)
    return r
```

The example which was given will first move the cursor to `2,16` on the screen (which is *past* the location of `item_name` — at column 10).  The `stdscr.getstr` call will not return the value of `item_name`; it will return *only* the characters which you enter using the keyboard.  As noted, [*window*`.instr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.instr) provides a way to combine the value of `item_name` and the `stdscr.getstr` call.

However, even that combination is not enough, since `stdscr.getstr` will return characters from *its* starting point.  So you could not, for instance, start the call at the end of the value written using `addstr`.  If you do this:

```
def Edit_Item(stdscr, item_name)
    stdscr.addstr(1, 2, "Item Name:" + item_name + "_" )
    r = stdscr.getstr(2, 10, 15)
    r = stdscr.instr(2, 10, 15)
    return r
```

it would be closer to your intent, but (untested) will probably erase the characters past the cursor position when you press <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you revised the solution to use `getch`, you can decide what to echo, as well as handling things such as left/right cursor movement within the edited line. Fancy things like editing a template string are usually built up from simpler functions.

Comment: Thank you but it probably does not feel right. :-( Embedded text 'Foo' on line 'Item Name:' must go to the edit screen.

Answer (score 0):

@Thomas Dickey:
No :-( I will try to better describe what I need..

```
- Call function 'Edit_Item' with parameter 'Foo'           # OK
- The screen prints 'Item Name: Foo'                       # OK
- Cursor is now behind the word 'Foo_'                     # OK
- Press the key arrow left (2x) to change the cursor 'F_o' # Not work
- Edit word 'Foo' to 'Fao'
```

It's to understand?

## # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

This is exactly what I need to do in curses.

Demonstration in Bash

```
read -e -i "Foo" -p "Edit Item Name: " ITEM
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

```
import curses
screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
curses.start_color()
screen.keypad( 1 )
screen.border( 0 )
curses.curs_set( 2 )
string = "Foo"
max_len = 40 #max len of string
screen.addstr( 3, 1, "Item Name: " )
screen.addstr( 3, 12, string )
screen.refresh()
position = len( string )
x = screen.getch( 3, 12 + position )
while x != 27:
    if (x <= 122 and x >= 97) or x == 32 or (x <= 90 and x >= 65):
        if position == len( string ):
            if len( string ) < max_len:
                string += chr( x )
                position = len( string )
        else:
            string = string[ 0:position ] + chr( x ) + string[ position + 1: ]
    if x == 263:
        if position == len( string ):
            string = string[ 0:len( string ) - 1 ]
            position = len( string )
        else:
            string = string[ 0:position -1 ] + string[ position: ]
            if position > 0:
                position -= 1
    if x == 330:
        if position == len( string ) - 1:
            string = string[ 0:len( string ) - 1 ]
        else:
            string = string[ 0:position +1] + string[ position + 2: ]
    if x == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
        if position < len( string ):
            position += 1
    if x == curses.KEY_LEFT:
        if position > 0:
            position -= 1  

    screen.erase()
    screen.border( 0 )
    screen.addstr( 3, 1, "Item Name: " )
    screen.addstr( 3, 12, string )
    x = screen.getch( 3, 12 + position )

curses.endwin()
exit()
```